# Anybody know what this DB25 jumper connection is called?

Tags: connector, jumper

I'm in the process of motorizing a few electronics project.  Been racking my brains with Google and Mouser trying to identify the following part that is connected to a DB25 connector.

It looks like some kind of board with header pins, but as I am an electronics novice have no idea what this is called.  Using jumper wires seems like a nicer semi-permanent solution than a breakout box.

Here's the suspect:

[image: db25 connector]

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: An alternative might be to search for a wire-wrap version of the DB25 connector; this will have suitably long 0.64mm square pins - IF they are still made...

Comment: Do the pins go through the board?  If so it sort of looks like right angle wire wrap parts, with an extra plastic molding like a set of header pins and a PCB added, perhaps for strength.  But if the PCB is joining distinct pins, then it's just an ordinary through hole right angle DB25 and a through hole header.

Comment: I've just looked up *DB25 breakout board*.  A number of parts similar to the O.P. photo came up.

Comment: Judging by the "brokenish" pin at the bottom, I would say it is much like the conclusion by Chris.

The breakout's are all about $15-$20, so will probably try and rig this myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a normal board-mount DB-25 mounted to a unusually small board.  The only other part on the board seems to be a header, which is what the jumper wires are connecting to.

This was probably done because the jumper wires you can easily get like that will be for .1" pitch, and the pins on the DB connector are a little off from that.  Also, the DB pins don't stick out very far on normal thru hole parts.

The part that isn't clear from the picture is whether either connector was thru hole or surface mount.  If the header was thru hole, you'd expect the pins to stick out the other side of the board a bit, but there doesn't seem to be space for that.  On the other hand, from what little we can see in the picture, there don't appear to be SMD pads.

Comment: Actually, the pin spacing for Dsubs is .109 inch.

Comment: @What: I have update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of these: -

[image]

And somebody has designed a little circuit board that solders to the pins and brings the connections out to a single 0.1" header. The header has a mating half fitted as per your picture.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity and future reference, managed to locate it.

[image]

http://www.technologicalarts.ca/shop/store/details/212/52/adapters/d-sub/d-sub-adapters,-25-pin-socket,-right-angle.html